# What does it mean that a markov information source is unifilar?

Tags: terminology, markov-chains

I'm reading up on markov chains and came across the following sentence on the wikipedia article on [Markov information source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_information_source)

*A unifilar Markov source is a Markov source for which the values ${\displaystyle f(s_{k})}$ are distinct whenever each of the states ${\displaystyle s_{k}} $ are reachable, in one step, from a common prior state*

Could someone elaborate on this?(the article is rather brief)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that our Markov chain $M$ is a random walk on a path of length $6$: the states are integers $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and at every step we go from state $i$ to state $i+1$ or $i-1$ with equal probability (except at $0$ and $6$, where we go to $1$ and $5$ respectively with probability $1$).

Here are two possible Markov information sources we can define on this Markov chain (our alphabet will be the English alphabet):

1. Define a function $f$ on $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ by $$f(0) = \textsf{G},\,f(1) = \textsf{E},\,f(2) = \textsf{O},\,f(3) = \textsf{R},\,f(4) = \textsf{G},\,f(5) = \textsf{I},\,f(6) = \textsf{A}.$$
2. Define a function $g$ on $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ by $$g(0) = \textsf{I},\,g(1) = \textsf{N},\,g(2) = \textsf{D},\,g(3) = \textsf{I},\,g(4) = \textsf{A},\,g(5) = \textsf{N},\,g(6) = \textsf{A}.$$

So if our random walk starts at state $0$ and happens to go $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, \dots$ then the Markov information source $(M,f)$ will produce a sequence beginning $\textsf{GEORGIGRORGR}\dots$ and the Markov information source $(M,g)$ will produce a sequence beginning $\textsf{INDIANAIDIAI}\dots$.

In this example, $(M,f)$ is unifilar: the neighbors of each state are assigned distinct letters. (It's okay that $f(0) = f(4) = \textsf{G}$, because there's no state that can transition to both $0$ and $4$.) However, $(M,g)$ is not unifilar: from state $5$ we can go to states $4$ and $6$, but $g(4) = g(6) = \textsf{A}$.

---

Roughly speaking, here is why this matters. With a unifilar information source such as $(M,f)$, if I tell you the starting state $X_0$ and then the sequence of letters produced up to some step $n$, you will be able to uniquely determine the intermediate states $X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}$ that the Markov chain visited and, most importantly, the state $X_n$ that the Markov chain ends up at. You can do this because from each state, the different transitions you can take produce different letters as output. As a result, it's very easy to compute the distribution of the next letter in the sequence.

If the Markov information source is *not* unifilar, then knowing the starting state and the letters produced does not tell you what states the Markov chain visited. For example, with $(M,f)$, the sequence of states $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ and $0,1,2,3,4,5,4$ produce the same sequence of letters $\textsf{INDIANA}$. We can still compute a distribution for the next letter, but it requires averaging: the final state is equally likely to be $4$ or $6$, so the next letter is $\textsf{I}$ with probability $\frac12 \cdot \frac12 + \frac12 \cdot 0$ and $\textsf{N}$ with probability $\frac12 \cdot \frac12 + \frac12 \cdot 1$.

In general, this averaging can get arbitrarily complicated. Maybe at some point we're equally likely to be in states $s_1$ and $s_2$; from $s_1$, the next states produce letters $\textsf{X}$ and $\textsf{Y}$ with equal probability, and from $s_2$, the next states are twice as likely to produce $\textsf{X}$ as $\textsf{Y}$. Then the correct thing to do upon seeing an $\textsf{X}$ as the next letter is to do a Bayesian update and conclude that with probability $\frac23$, we were actually at $s_2$ and not $s_1$. This, of course, affects the distribution of the next letter...